# Is there a way to move a picture using arrow keys for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF, and I am trying to make an RPG using 2D Sprite gif files for animations for walking forward, backward, etc.

I am having issues making the original picture move in any direction using the arrow keys. Here is the snippet of code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextofTheWild2._0.Screen1" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:gif="https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif"

             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextofTheWild2._0"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             FocusManager.FocusedElement = "{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas}">

    <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Background="#FFFCD8A8" KeyDown="Canvas_OnKeyDown" Focusable="True" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" Background="#FF00A800" Canvas.Left="390"/>
        <TextBlock Height="40" Canvas.Left="149" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Press E to activate" Canvas.Top="40" Width="52" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" Background="#FF00A800"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Background="Black" Canvas.Left="27" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Background="#FF00A800"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" Background="#FF00A800" Canvas.Top="269"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Background="#FF00A800" Canvas.Left="778" Canvas.Top="269"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Background="#FF00A800" Canvas.Top="370"/>
        <Image Name="Green_Link" Height="93"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="480" Canvas.Top="259" Width="85" gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="Assets/Green Link idle.gif" Source="Assets/Green Link idle.gif" Focusable="True"/>
        <Image Name="Blue_Link" Height="93"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="390" Canvas.Top="259" Width="85" gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="Assets/Blue Link idle.gif" Source="Assets/Blue Link idle.gif"/>
        <Image Name="Red_Link" Height="93"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="305" Canvas.Top="259" Width="85" gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="Assets/Red Link Idle.gif" Source="Assets/Red Link Idle.gif"/>
        <Image Name="Purple_Link" Height="93"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="220" Canvas.Top="259" Width="85" gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="Assets/Purple Link idle.gif" Source="Assets/Purple Link idle.gif"/>



    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

For XAML, and the code behind it:

```
public partial class Screen1 : UserControl
{
    public Screen1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void Canvas_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(Green_Link, Canvas.GetTop(Green_Link) + 10);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(Green_Link, Canvas.GetTop(Green_Link) - 10);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Green_Link, Canvas.GetLeft(Green_Link) - 10);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Green_Link, Canvas.GetLeft(Green_Link) + 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Before I start working on transitional animations, I would like to at least get the images to move in the canvas. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The Arrow Keys do not move the images on the program when executed

Comment: Have you checked if Canvas_KeyDown is called?

Comment: If not, set `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` on the Canvas.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with the name of the method. You have Canvas_OnKeyDown in XAML and Canvas_KeyDown defined in Screen1. You may also be putting your C# code in the wrong file - your XAML indicates the codebehind file you want is GameWindow.xaml.cs, not Screen1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've put your C# code in the wrong place. The start of your XAML file says this:

`<x:Name="WINDow" x:Class="TextofTheWild2._0.GameWindow" ...`

This means that your xaml file is partially defining a class called `GameWindow`. This'll be made up of two files, the xaml and the codebehind (which has extension .xaml.cs). When you handle an event in xaml like you're doing (ie. `KeyDown="Canvas_OnKeyDown"`), it gets routed to a function in the codebehind for that view.

If you put your `Canvas_KeyDown` method in GameWindow.xaml.cs (and rename the method to `Canvas_OnKeyDown` - you were missing an `On`), WPF should pick up and it should work correctly.

Comment: I reread through the post just a moment ago and it seems I sent the wrong XAML File. i'll edit the post real quick. sorry about that.